# WordPress Plugin Development - Post request

Tags: wordpress, plugins

Am developing wordpress plugin that makes donation,  through lcoal online payment providers. After payment complete a post request should be sent to the website.
My question is how to make specific wordpress page receive post request using the plugin i created

Comment: Hi. Stackoverflow isn't a tutorial site. If you have specific question, relative a problem in your code, the community can help you. Try to do some research on google, if you need some tutorial on how to do what you need

Comment: Hi, you can answer my question or give me a useful link

Comment: **Try to do some research on google, if you need some tutorial on how to do what you need**

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, this question is unclear.

But to what I understand, you want that a specific page that would be provided by a user of your plugin, be called upon completion of the payment.
Your plugin would allow entering that page in the plugin's configuration.

If it's that, as an example, Paypal does it : See https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/step_3/, **Take customers to this URL when they finish checkout** : They call back the URL passed to their site, upon payment completion.

In your case, you must see with your local online payment provider if he supports that feature and call it with such URL as parameter.